# Is it more affective to keep general jars in server lib, then have it as part of war distribution?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, dependencies, war

I am currently in the project, that has multiple wars, with similar dependencies: Spring, Hibernate, Guava, e t.c. I am thinking of moving those dependencies to server lib folder for optimization:

Obvious downside of such approach

1. This would increase complexity of the environment
2. This would increase complexity of the dependencies management for the project.

There fore my questions:

1. Is it worth doing? (Meaning will there be any benefits,from performance and memory, point of view? (Or it's just another headache))
2. Are there any tools to make such transition smoother?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this go both ways.  Personally, I prefer when the dependencies are packaged inside the deliverable -- the WAR/EAR has the spring, hibernate etc jars within itself.  Otherwise, you need a whole different release strategy to manage the dependencies deployed to the server, and may the Universe pity you if you ever need to deploy incompatible versions of dependencies to the same service.

On the downside, it potentially increases duplication, as these resources might exist in multiple webapps ... but really, is the volume where you deploy your application really that constrained?

Comment: I totally agry, in regards of complexity, that's why I am interested in the tools, that can help with that, so it would be more of a configuration problem.

Comment: Chef is usually cited as a tool to manage platform deployments and configuration.  But beware that you will eventually find this model very limiting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is more efficient to put the common jars for different wars in server/lib directory. But then it introduces more work for you installer to copy those jars to the desired folder.

**Note of caution**

This approach of putting common jars in server/lib is useful when all the different web applications are using the same version of jars. If different web apps need different version of same jar then avoid putting it in the server/lib. Otherwise you will run into problems of referring to wrong class version and may follow other errors.